# Using somekind of mechanism to trim the return value from method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got service api. There are some methods in my `Base` class and I have concrete implementations inheriting this class and implementing its methods. I've got few implementors of `Base` class.

I've got about 20 methods and I want to trim the return values from all of those methods. But I'm hesitant to add the bit of code which trims the return value to each of 20 methods. I was looking for a better way to do this.

I though I found it here :

http://cheind.blogspot.com/2008/12/method-hooks-in-ruby.html

But this approach only works on my `Base` class and not on the classes who implement the `Base` class. How can apply it to all my implementor classes?

Comment: Can't you make an intermediate class that has the trim wrapper methods? What about a `module` you can `include` that layers on this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it would make sense to implement the Presenter (a.k.a Exhibit) Pattern. The basic concept is to wrap your object with a proxy which adds a layer of presentation logic. You can find more about this pattern here:

- [Ruby on Rails patterns - decorator vs presenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860301/rails-patterns-decorator-vs-presenter)
- https://gist.github.com/jordelver/3230399
- http://www.saturnflyer.com/blog/jim/2013/03/21/ruby-delegate-rb-secrets/
- http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2011-09-09-better-ruby-presenters

Getting to some real code, you could imagine having a class like this one:

```
class Test
  def baked
    "  baked"
  end

  def beans
    "  beans  "
  end

  def food_methods
    [:baked, :beans]
  end
end

test = Test.new
p "#{test.baked} #{test.beans}"
```

The Ruby Standard Library offers a neat utility called SimpleDelegator which offers most of the functionalities that we need. Therefore we just need to dinamically define some methods and wrap the original object in a new *presented* object:

```
require 'delegate'

class TestPresenter < SimpleDelegator
  Test.new.food_methods.each do |method|
    define_method(method) do |*args|
      __getobj__.send(method, *args).strip
    end
  end
end

presenter = TestPresenter.new(test)
p "#{presenter.baked} #{presenter.beans}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this solution isn't as "clean" as @ju-liu's, and it probably isn't the most efficient, but it is shorter and easier to implement in your workflow. You'd also probably want to limit the methods to be redefined and build in better error handling.

Inside your `Base` class you could do:

```
(Base.instance_methods - Class.instance_methods).each do |method|  
  alias_method "#{method}_backup", method    
  class_eval %Q{    
    def #{method}(*args)
      #{method}_backup(*args).strip rescue #{method}_backup(*args)
    end
  }
end
```