# Using the controller to manage render logic rather than view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm not asking for code as an answer, rather, a resource or some general guidance.

I have an index page of users. For each user, I check the "friend status" of each user in respect to the current user. As you can imagine, it is a pretty lengthy if and elsif statements in the view page.. which is basically:

```
<% if current_user %>
    <% if current_user.friend_with? profile.user %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
    <% elsif current_user.invited_by? profile.user %>
        <%= link_to '.', friendship_path(profile.user), :method => "put", :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-check" %>
    <% elsif current_user.connected_with? profile.user %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" title="Pending approval"></span>
    <% elsif current_user == profile.user %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to '.', friendships_path(:user_id => profile), :method => "post", :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-plus" %>
```

I have this entire logic in the view page, and it is very cumbersome. I would like to clean it up a little and stash it away in the controller (if advisable).

Any guidance would be really appreciated. I imagine having a method to return the type of icon or to render some kind of html code and pass it into the view. Thanks!!

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Use a helper or partial?

Comment: Also make sure you actually provide some kind of meaningful text inside those links for people who use screen readers.

Comment: yea i understand to use helper, but any guidance on generating html code through a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helper method is the answer..

Move it in some method in your helper like

```
def my_awesome_helper_method
- logic -
end
```

and in the view just call

```
<%=my_awesome_helper_method %>
```

much cleaner...!

Comment: thank you  - what language/syntax do we use to return html code from the generator? for example, within the helper method, i want to return <span><div class="x"></div></span>, how do i write that up in the controller?

Comment: you can either use content_tag or return it as string and use a htmlsafe

Comment: also not in controller this should go in a helper class which is app/helpers folder

Answer (score 0):

You should look into https://stackoverflow.com/a/7860493/1657377, a presenter or decorator pattern might fit in here. But this logic definitely does not belong into the controller.